# jQuery Toggle open all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm needing to run a script that I made, it's pretty basic but it is working, but not the way I want, I made this code because I could not find any that could modify

HTML:

```
<div class="corpo">
    <div class="menu-segmento">
        <div class="item total">
            <div class="item-topo">
                <div class="tooltips" >
                    <img class="ocultar" src="img/ocultar.png" />
                    <span>Veja menos</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="tooltips" >
                    <img class="mostrar" src="img/mostrar.png" />
                    <span>Veja mais</span>  
                </div>
                <p>Drenagem Linfática</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="segmento">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel velit nulla. Vestibulum sollicitudin sed sapien faucibus porta. Maecenas quis fringilla felis. Vestibulum ultricies quis orci et auctor. Suspendisse vitae mi odio. Maecenas tincidunt nisl sit amet ante ullamcorper bibendum. Vivamus et vestibulum velit. Proin cursus est quis velit euismod, vitae eleifend nisi ultrices. Proin nec felis lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="item total">
            <div class="item-topo">
                <div class="tooltips" >
                    <img class="ocultar" src="img/ocultar.png" />
                    <span>Veja menos</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="tooltips" >
                    <img class="mostrar" src="img/mostrar.png" />
                    <span>Veja mais</span>  
                </div>
                <p>Drenagem Linfática</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="segmento">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel velit nulla. Vestibulum sollicitudin sed sapien faucibus porta. Maecenas quis fringilla felis. Vestibulum ultricies quis orci et auctor. Suspendisse vitae mi odio. Maecenas tincidunt nisl sit amet ante ullamcorper bibendum. Vivamus et vestibulum velit. Proin cursus est quis velit euismod, vitae eleifend nisi ultrices. Proin nec felis lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the JS for jQuery

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand
    var flip = 0;
    $('.mostrar').click( function(){
       $('.segmento').slideToggle();
       $('.mostrar').fadeOut();
       $('.ocultar').fadeIn();
    }); 
    $('.ocultar').click( function(){
       $('.segmento').slideToggle();
       $('.ocultar').fadeOut();
       $('.mostrar').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

He is opening the 2 and know it is missing a line of code but I have no idea how to fix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you got it all wrong. You're hiding the image but leaving the text. Makes sense?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pA3xJ/

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OMEhePuC/1/edit)**

If you have i.e this CSS:

```
.segmento, .ocultar{
  display:none;
}
```

Remove the classes from the images and add to `.tooltips`:

```
  <div class="corpo">
    <div class="menu-segmento">
        <div class="item total">
            <div class="item-topo">
                <div class="tooltips ocultar">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f00&text=ocultar" />
                    <span>Veja menos</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="tooltips mostrar" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/cf5&text=mostrar" />
                    <span>Veja mais</span>  
                </div>
                <p>Drenagem Linfática</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="segmento">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel velit nulla. Vestibulum sollicitudin sed sapien faucibus porta. Maecenas quis fringilla felis. Vestibulum ultricies quis orci et auctor. Suspendisse vitae mi odio. Maecenas tincidunt nisl sit amet ante ullamcorper bibendum. Vivamus et vestibulum velit. Proin cursus est quis velit euismod, vitae eleifend nisi ultrices. Proin nec felis lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="item total">
            <div class="item-topo">
                <div class="tooltips ocultar" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f00&text=ocultar" />
                    <span>Veja menos</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="tooltips mostrar" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/cf5&text=mostrar" />
                    <span>Veja mais</span>  
                </div>
                <p>Drenagem Linfática</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="segmento">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel velit nulla. Vestibulum sollicitudin sed sapien faucibus porta. Maecenas quis fringilla felis. Vestibulum ultricies quis orci et auctor. Suspendisse vitae mi odio. Maecenas tincidunt nisl sit amet ante ullamcorper bibendum. Vivamus et vestibulum velit. Proin cursus est quis velit euismod, vitae eleifend nisi ultrices. Proin nec felis lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is all you need:

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand 
    $('.mostrar, .ocultar').click( function(){
       var $parent = $(this).closest('.item');
       $(this).toggle().siblings().toggle();
       $parent.find('.segmento').slideToggle();
    });  
});
```